# SAS email with let reference in text

Tags: email, sas

I have the email sender in SAS, code looks like:

```
data _null_; 
   file outbox 

      from='aaa@mail.ru' 
      to=("bbb@mail.ru")    
      subject="New version of view";

   put 'Hello';    
   put 'View has neen updated'; 
run;
```

I need to add my date let reference into mail part, that finally should look like:

```
"Hello.
View on 01.01.2019 has been updated."
```

Tried to use &report_date. in put statement - but it finally look like text.
What should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Single quotation versus double quotation might be the trick. put "View has been updated ver &version.";

Comment: Show the code where you as assign `report_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `MMDDYYP10.` format.  You will have to use the report_date parameter (presumed to be a macro variable holding a date constant as source code text) in data step variable assignment in order to be able to apply the format in a `put`.

```
%let report_date = '01-JAN-2019'D;

data _null_;
  put 'Hello';
  date = &report_date;
  put 'View on ' date mmddyyp10. ' has been updated';
run;
```